# How to apply tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer on tf.data.TextLineDataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tokenize

I am loading a `TextLineDataset` and I want to apply a tokenizer trained on a file:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename)

MAX_WORDS = 20000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([x.numpy().decode('utf-8') for x in train_data])
```

Now I want to apply this tokenizer on `data` so that each word is replaced with its encoded value. I have tried `data.map(lambda x: tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x))` which gives `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over` tf.Tensor `is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.`

Following the instruction, when I write the code as:

```py
@tf.function
def fun(x):
    return tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x)
train_data.map(lambda x: fun(x))
```

I get: `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over` tf.Tensor `is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature`.

So how to do the tokenization on `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` is not meant to be used in graph mode. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer?version=nightly#texts_to_sequences), both `fit_on_texts` and `texts_to_sequences` require lists of strings and not tensors. I would recommend using `tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization`, but if you really want to use the `Tokenizer` approach, try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('this is a very important sentence \n')
  f.write('where is my cat actually?\n')
  f.write('fish are everywhere!\n')

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(['/content/data.txt'])

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([n.numpy().decode("utf-8")for n in list(dataset.map(lambda x: x))])

def tokenize(x):
  return tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([x.numpy().decode("utf-8")])

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(tokenize, [x], Tout=[tf.int32])[0])

for d in dataset:
  print(d)
```

```
tf.Tensor([2 1 3 4 5 6], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 7  1  8  9 10], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([11 12 13], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

Using the `TextVectorization` layer would look something like this:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('this is a very important sentence \n')
  f.write('where is my cat actually?\n')
  f.write('fish are everywhere!\n')

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(['/content/data.txt'])

vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(output_mode='int')
vectorize_layer.adapt(dataset)

dataset = dataset.map(vectorize_layer)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `TextVectorization` layer. ^_^